# How do you adapt this 8-bit bit-buffer implementation to be 32-bit?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I got this from [GitHub](https://github.com/inolen/bit-buffer).

```
function LittleEndianView(size) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'native', {
    value: new Uint8Array(size)
  })
}

LittleEndianView.prototype.get = function(bits, offset) {
  let available = (this.native.length * 8 - offset)

  if (bits > available) {
    throw new Error('Range error')
  }

  let value = 0
  let i = 0
  // why loop through like this?
  while (i < bits) {
    // remaining bits
    const remaining = bits - i
    const bitOffset = offset & 7
    const currentByte = this.native[offset >> 3]

    const read = Math.min(remaining, 8 - bitOffset)

    const a = 0xFF << read
    mask = ~a
    const b = currentByte >> bitOffset
    readBits = b & mask

    const c = readBits << i

    value = value | c
    offset += read
    i += read
  }

  return value >>> 0
}

LittleEndianView.prototype.set = function(bits, offset) {
  const available = (this.native.length * 8 - offset)

  if (bits > available) {
    throw new Error('Range error')
  }

  let i = 0
  while (i < bits) {
    const remaining = bits - i
    const bitOffset = offset & 7
    const byteOffset = offset >> 3
    const finished = Math.min(remaining, 8 - bitOffset)

    const mask = ~(0xFF << finished)
    const writeBits = value & mask
    const value >>= finished

    const destMask = ~(mask << bitOffset)
    const byte = this.view[byteOffset]

    this.native[byteOffset] = (byte & destMask) | (writeBits << bitOffset)

    offset += finished
    i += finished
  }
}
```

After studying it for a few hours, I realize that the `offset & 7` is only keeping the first 3 bits of the offset, which is for 1 byte. The `offset >> 3` is simply dividing the offset by 8 to go from bits to bytes. The `0xFF << read` is to get a bunch of 1s on the left like `11111000`. Then negate it to get them on the right. I understand most of it just barely in pieces. But I don't see how they figured out how to implement this solution using these techniques (and I don't fully grasp the whole solution -- how or why it works -- after a couple days at this).

So that leads me to the question, I need to apply this same read/write functionality to a `Uint32Array` in JavaScript (rather than a `Uint8Array` like the above code would use). I need to read and write arbitrary bits (not bytes) to this `Uint32Array`. What needs to change in the existing `get` and `set` algorithms to accommodate this?

Seems like the `offset & 7` might become something different, but I can't tell how to get it to be 32 bit representation. And the `offset >> 3` might become divide by 32 or something like that. But I'm not sure. That may be mostly it.

Comment: *" I need to apply this same read/write functionality to a Uint32Array in JavaScript"* Why? the `Uint8Array` is a private property (a cache) for the `LittleEndianView`. This "View" doesn't even allow you to work on an arbitrary `ArrayBuffer`. Why do you think you need an `Uint32Array`? This feels like an AB problem